# How would I modify an existing line in the sssd.conf file with puppet?

Tags: puppet

Very new to puppet here.  I want to be able to modify group members that are allowed to authenticate via LDAP to our servers.  This is done by modifying the "simple_allow_groups" line in the "sssd.conf" file.  How would I have puppet append a string to a specific line in the sssd.conf file if it doesn't already exist?  For example, the line may look like:

```
simple_allow_groups = group1,Group2
```

and I want it to look like:

```
simple_allow_groups = group1,Group2,group3
```

How would I accomplish this in puppet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can manage the entire file and use the `file` resource type with the appropriate `source` or `content` option or, since `sssd.conf` uses the ini file format, you can manage that setting with [inifile module](https://forge.puppet.com/puppetlabs/inifile).